# MVC Maintaining values between two actions for progress bar in mvc

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

i have a ActionResult which calls an API and returns data but it takes a lot of time so i wanted to display a progress bar ,so i made a ajax call to another ActionResult and maintain data between them using session but it is not working for multiple request and also it results in delay because of session locking is there a better way to do this
my first action2 is executing like a loop and i need that loop value in action1 to display progress and return it to ajax call

my code is something like this :-

```
 setInterval(extendsession, 2000);
    function extendsession() {
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("Action1", "Controller")',
            type: 'get',

            async:true,
            success: function (result) {
                $("#status").html(result);
                var progress = []; var progressPercentage;
                if (result != "") {
                    progress = result.split(",");
                    progressPercentage = (progress[1]);
                }

                $("#progressbar").progressbar({
                    value: parseInt(progressPercentage)
                });
            },

        });
```

and Actions are

```
public ActionResult Action2()
        { 
while(true)
do api call..
         Session["ProgressPercentage"]   //sava data in session
}

//below action is called by ajax to get progress
public string Action1()
{
return Session["ProgressPercentage"].toString(); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDITED**

```
  public ActionResult acetion1()
  { //Api call
    TempData["Result"] = "ProgressPercentage";
  } 

public ActionResult action2()
{
    var result= TempData["Result"];
    return result;
}
```

Comment: no actually i have to get the data and return it in ajax so i need a better way to share it first between actions,using sessions are causing problems like session locking etc.

Comment: temp data is lost in this multiple requests as i use setInterval;

Comment: @Rushee - you do know that TempData uses Session, right?

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch Yes I know that